# Nunjucks Async DB Call for CMS

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, express, nunjucks

My project was originally set up with Handlebars, but I'm moving to Nunjucks due to it's ability to perform async logic. I've been reading through the docs, but I'm not exactly sure how to do this. If I understand correctly, you cannot use Express' rendering engine and instead have to implement a custom template loader yourself. How would you execute a db call from a custom helper, then render the template with the fetched data?